# Change the icon of an image list created with bbui.js (data-bb-img)

Tags: javascript, blackberry-webworks

[bbUI.js](https://github.com/blackberry/bbUI.js) creates an image list optimized for finger usage from this syntax

```
<div data-bb-type="screen">
    <div data-bb-type="image-list">
        <div data-bb-type="item" data-bb-img="icon1.png" data-bb-title="Hi">foo</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It creates this HTML:

```
<div id="1" class="bb-hires-image-list-item" data-bb-type="item" onmouseover="this.setAttribute('class','bb-hires-image-list-item-hover')" onmouseout="this.setAttribute('class','bb-hires-image-list-item')" x-blackberry-focusable="true">
<img src="images/icons/icon11.png">
<div class="details">
    <span class="title">Hi</span>
    <div class="description">foo</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Now, I would like to change both the img src and the foo in the description div, but I did not find a way to do that with Javascript, I would do a "getElementById", but it doesn't have an ID.

How I could do that?